# How I can compare this time with other in cakePHP 2x

Tags: date, cakephp

I have the following conditions in my query:

```
 'conditions' => array('Zona.nombre LIKE' => $buscar,
      'date_format("%Y", Zona.created)' => 'date_format("%Y", NOW())',
```

How do I get result of current year ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CakePHP you can simply do this:

```
 'YEAR(Zona.created)' => date('Y'),
```

Comment: that is working for me in cakephp 2x. try it out properly.

Comment: Excuse, I need other sentence, but this work in my proyect, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done something like that.

```
"DATE_FORMAT(Zona.created, '%Y') = " => "DATE_FORMAT(YEAR(), '%Y')",
```